# ARMv5 with Valgrind: illegal instruction

Tags: arm, valgrind, cross-compiling, memcheck

thanks to other posts here, I managed to build and install Valgrind for ARM:

```
make clean
make distclean

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/angstrom/arm/bin
export CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/local/angstrom/arm/bin/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi-
export CC=${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc
export CPP=${CROSS_COMPILE}cpp
export CXX=${CROSS_COMPILE}g++
export LD=${CROSS_COMPILE}ld
export AR=${CROSS_COMPILE}ar
export RANLIB=${CROSS_COMPILE}ranlib

sed -i -e "s#armv7#arm#g" configure

./configure   --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi \
    --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi \
          --prefix=/opt/valgrind/ \
          CFLAGS=-static

make

make install
```

and copied it into the same path on the ARMv5 machine.

I am running an ARMv5 and apparently Valgrind is still not supporting ARMv5.

When starting Valgrind, I'll get

```
Illegal instruction
```

and I suppose this is, because Valgrind needs the ARMv7 instruction set?

So:

- did I make any error in configure when cross-compiling valgrind?
- is there any way to get Valgrind up and running on ARMv5 or even only the vgdb or Memcheck tool included in Valgrind?

Is there any other tool to do memchecks on ARMv5, I have heard about

- Adress Sanitizer or
- Malloc_Check

and are they recommendable for ARMv5?

Thanks a lot for help and support!
BR Florian

I have created a core dump and run gdb, unfortunately without debugging symbols:

**What command should i used?**

```
[New Thread 10495]
Core was generated by `/opt/valgrind/bin/valgrind'.
Program terminated with signal 4, Illegal instruction.
#0  0x38035804 in ?? ()
(gdb) list
305                  platform ? platform : "unknown");
306 
307    return platform;
308 }
309 
310 /* Where we expect to find all our aux files */
311 static const char *valgrind_lib = VG_LIBDIR;
312 
313 int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp)
314 {
(gdb) info frame
Stack level 0, frame at 0x38ac7894:
 pc = 0x38035804; saved pc 0x380425e0
 called by frame at 0x38ac7894
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
 Arglist at 0x38ac7894, args: 
 Locals at 0x38ac7894, Previous frame's sp is 0x38ac7894
(gdb) list main
326 
327    /* Start the debugging-log system ASAP.  First find out how many 
328       "-d"s were specified.  This is a pre-scan of the command line.
329       At the same time, look for the tool name. */
330    loglevel = 0;
331    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
332       if (argv[i][0] != '-') {
333          clientname = argv[i];
334          break;
335       }
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x000087b4 <+0>: cmp r0, #1
   0x000087b8 <+4>: push    {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, r10, r11, lr}
   0x000087bc <+8>: mov r10, r0
   0x000087c0 <+12>:    sub sp, sp, #12
   0x000087c4 <+16>:    mov r11, r1
   0x000087c8 <+20>:    mov r9, r2
   0x000087cc <+24>:    ble 0x8c90 <main+1244>
   0x000087d0 <+28>:    ldr r4, [r1, #4]
   0x000087d4 <+32>:    ldrb    r3, [r4]

   0x000087d8 <+36>:    cmp r3, #45 ; 0x2d
   0x000087dc <+40>:    movne   r8, #0
   0x000087e0 <+44>:    movne   r7, r8
   0x000087e4 <+48>:    bne 0x8820 <main+108>
   0x000087e8 <+52>:    ldr r0, [pc, #1372] ; 0x8d4c <main+1432>
   0x000087ec <+56>:    bl  0x29d20 <strlen>
   0x000087f0 <+60>:    mov r8, #0
   0x000087f4 <+64>:    mov r5, #1
   0x000087f8 <+68>:    mov r7, r8
   0x000087fc <+72>:    mov r6, r0
   0x00008800 <+76>:    cmp r6, #3
   0x00008804 <+80>:    bhi 0x8b70 <main+956>
   0x00008808 <+84>:    cmp r6, #0
   0x0000880c <+88>:    bne 0x8a00 <main+588>
   0x00008810 <+92>:    add r0, r5, #1
   0x00008814 <+96>:    cmp r10, r0
   0x00008818 <+100>:   ble 0x8b90 <main+988>
   0x0000881c <+104>:   ldr r4, [r11, r0, lsl #2]
   0x00008820 <+108>:   mov r0, r8
   0x00008824 <+112>:   ldr r1, [pc, #1316] ; 0x8d50 <main+1436>
   0x00008828 <+116>:   bl  0xa258 <vgPlain_debugLog_startup>
   0x0000882c <+120>:   cmp r7, #0
   0x00008830 <+124>:   mov r10, r7
   0x00008834 <+128>:   beq 0x8bac <main+1016>
   0x00008838 <+132>:   mov r3, r7
   0x0000883c <+136>:   mov r0, #1
   0x00008840 <+140>:   ldr r1, [pc, #1292] ; 0x8d54 <main+1440>
   0x00008844 <+144>:   ldr r2, [pc, #1292] ; 0x8d58 <main+1444>
   0x00008848 <+148>:   bl  0x9ff0 <vgPlain_debugLog>
   0x0000884c <+152>:   cmp r4, #0
   0x00008850 <+156>:   beq 0x8bc8 <main+1044>
   0x00008854 <+160>:   mov r0, r4
   0x00008858 <+164>:   bl  0x8278 <select_platform>
   0x0000885c <+168>:   subs    r8, r0, #0
   0x00008860 <+172>:   beq 0x8c6c <main+1208>
   0x00008864 <+176>:   mov r0, #1
   0x00008868 <+180>:   ldr r1, [pc, #1252] ; 0x8d54 <main+1440>
   0x0000886c <+184>:   ldr r2, [pc, #1256] ; 0x8d5c <main+1448>
   0x00008870 <+188>:   mov r3, r8
   0x00008874 <+192>:   bl  0x9ff0 <vgPlain_debugLog>
   0x00008878 <+196>:   mov r0, #0
   0x0000887c <+200>:   mov r5, r0
   0x00008880 <+204>:   add r4, r0, #500    ; 0x1f4
   0x00008884 <+208>:   mov r1, r4
   0x00008888 <+212>:   mov r0, r5
   0x0000888c <+216>:   bl  0x290ec <realloc>
   0x00008890 <+220>:   subs    r5, r0, #0
   0x00008894 <+224>:   beq 0x8c88 <main+1236>
   0x00008898 <+228>:   ldr r0, [pc, #1216] ; 0x8d60 <main+1452>
   0x0000889c <+232>:   mov r1, r5
   0x000088a0 <+236>:   mov r2, r4
   0x000088a4 <+240>:   bl  0x2d760 <readlink>
   0x000088a8 <+244>:   cmn r0, #1
   0x000088ac <+248>:   beq 0x8c44 <main+1168>
   0x000088b0 <+252>:   cmp r0, r4
   0x000088b4 <+256>:   beq 0x8880 <main+204>
   0x000088b8 <+260>:   movcc   r3, #0
   0x000088bc <+264>:   movcc   r6, r5
   0x000088c0 <+268>:   strbcc  r3, [r5, r0]
   0x000088c4 <+272>:   bcs 0x8d38 <main+1412>
   0x000088c8 <+276>:   ldr r0, [pc, #1172] ; 0x8d64 <main+1456>
   0x000088cc <+280>:   bl  0x29d20 <strlen>
   0x000088d0 <+284>:   mov r4, r0
   0x000088d4 <+288>:   mov r0, r6
   0x000088d8 <+292>:   bl  0x29d20 <strlen>
   0x000088dc <+296>:   add r4, r4, r0
   0x000088e0 <+300>:   add r0, r4, #2
   0x000088e4 <+304>:   bl  0x28928 <malloc>
   0x000088e8 <+308>:   subs    r7, r0, #0
   0x000088ec <+312>:   beq 0x8ca4 <main+1264>
   0x000088f0 <+316>:   ldr r1, [pc, #1132] ; 0x8d64 <main+1456>
   0x000088f4 <+320>:   bl  0x29b00 <strcpy>
   0x000088f8 <+324>:   ldr r1, [pc, #1128] ; 0x8d68 <main+1460>
   0x000088fc <+328>:   mov r0, r7
   0x00008900 <+332>:   bl  0x29994 <strcat>
   0x00008904 <+336>:   mov r0, r7
   0x00008908 <+340>:   mov r1, r6
   0x0000890c <+344>:   bl  0x29994 <strcat>
   0x00008910 <+348>:   ldr r3, [r9]
   0x00008914 <+352>:   cmp r3, #0
   0x00008918 <+356>:   moveq   r4, r3
   0x0000891c <+360>:   moveq   r5, #2
   0x00008920 <+364>:   moveq   r0, #8
   0x00008924 <+368>:   beq 0x8944 <main+400>
   0x00008928 <+372>:   mov r4, #0
   0x0000892c <+376>:   add r4, r4, #1
   0x00008930 <+380>:   ldr r3, [r9, r4, lsl #2]
   0x00008934 <+384>:   cmp r3, #0
   0x00008938 <+388>:   bne 0x892c <main+376>
   0x0000893c <+392>:   add r5, r4, #2
   0x00008940 <+396>:   lsl r0, r5, #2
   0x00008944 <+400>:   bl  0x28928 <malloc>
   0x00008948 <+404>:   subs    r6, r0, #0
   0x0000894c <+408>:   beq 0x8cac <main+1272>
   0x00008950 <+412>:   cmp r4, #0
   0x00008954 <+416>:   moveq   r1, r4
   0x00008958 <+420>:   moveq   r0, #4
   0x0000895c <+424>:   moveq   r2, #2
   0x00008960 <+428>:   beq 0x8994 <main+480>
   0x00008964 <+432>:   mov r1, #0
   0x00008968 <+436>:   mov r2, r1
   0x0000896c <+440>:   ldr r3, [r9, r2]
   0x00008970 <+444>:   add r1, r1, #1
   0x00008974 <+448>:   cmp r4, r1
   0x00008978 <+452>:   str r3, [r6, r2]
   0x0000897c <+456>:   add r2, r2, #4
   0x00008980 <+460>:   bgt 0x896c <main+440>
   0x00008984 <+464>:   add r3, r4, #1
   0x00008988 <+468>:   add r2, r3, #1
   0x0000898c <+472>:   lsl r1, r4, #2
   0x00008990 <+476>:   lsl r0, r3, #2
   0x00008994 <+480>:   cmp r2, r5
   0x00008998 <+484>:   str r7, [r6, r1]
   0x0000899c <+488>:   mov r3, #0
   0x000089a0 <+492>:   str r3, [r6, r0]
   0x000089a4 <+496>:   bne 0x8cb4 <main+1280>
   0x000089a8 <+500>:   ldr r0, [pc, #956]  ; 0x8d6c <main+1464>
   0x000089ac <+504>:   bl  0x12650 <getenv>
   0x000089b0 <+508>:   subs    r3, r0, #0
   0x000089b4 <+512>:   ldrne   r0, [pc, #948]  ; 0x8d70 <main+1468>
   0x000089b8 <+516>:   ldreq   r0, [pc, #944]  ; 0x8d70 <main+1468>
   0x000089bc <+520>:   strne   r3, [r0]
   0x000089c0 <+524>:   ldr r0, [r0]
   0x000089c4 <+528>:   bl  0x29d20 <strlen>
   0x000089c8 <+532>:   mov r4, r0
   0x000089cc <+536>:   mov r0, r10
   0x000089d0 <+540>:   bl  0x29d20 <strlen>
   0x000089d4 <+544>:   mov r5, r0
   0x000089d8 <+548>:   mov r0, r8
   0x000089dc <+552>:   bl  0x29d20 <strlen>
   0x000089e0 <+556>:   add r4, r4, r5
   0x000089e4 <+560>:   add r4, r4, #3
   0x000089e8 <+564>:   add r0, r4, r0
   0x000089ec <+568>:   bl  0x28928 <malloc>
   0x000089f0 <+572>:   subs    r4, r0, #0
   0x000089f4 <+576>:   bne 0x8cc8 <main+1300>
   0x000089f8 <+580>:   ldr r0, [pc, #884]  ; 0x8d74 <main+1472>
   0x000089fc <+584>:   bl  0x8234 <barf>
   0x00008a00 <+588>:   ldrb    r2, [r4, #1]
   0x00008a04 <+592>:   cmp r6, #1
   0x00008a08 <+596>:   movls   r3, #0
   0x00008a0c <+600>:   movhi   r3, #1
   0x00008a10 <+604>:   cmp r2, #45 ; 0x2d
   0x00008a14 <+608>:   movne   r3, #0
   0x00008a18 <+612>:   cmp r3, #0
   0x00008a1c <+616>:   sub r0, r2, #45 ; 0x2d
   0x00008a20 <+620>:   beq 0x8a50 <main+668>
   0x00008a24 <+624>:   ldrb    r0, [r4, #2]
   0x00008a28 <+628>:   cmp r6, #2
   0x00008a2c <+632>:   movls   r3, #0
   0x00008a30 <+636>:   movhi   r3, #1
   0x00008a34 <+640>:   cmp r0, #0
   0x00008a38 <+644>:   movne   r3, #0
   0x00008a3c <+648>:   cmp r3, #0
   0x00008a40 <+652>:   ldrne   r1, [pc, #772]  ; 0x8d4c <main+1432>
   0x00008a44 <+656>:   ldrbne  r2, [r4, #3]
   0x00008a48 <+660>:   ldrbne  r3, [r1, #3]
   0x00008a4c <+664>:   rsbne   r0, r3, r2
   0x00008a50 <+668>:   cmp r0, #0
   0x00008a54 <+672>:   beq 0x8810 <main+92>
   0x00008a58 <+676>:   ldr r0, [pc, #792]  ; 0x8d78 <main+1476>
   0x00008a5c <+680>:   bl  0x29d20 <strlen>
   0x00008a60 <+684>:   cmp r0, #3
   0x00008a64 <+688>:   bhi 0x8c10 <main+1116>
   0x00008a68 <+692>:   cmp r0, #0
   0x00008a6c <+696>:   beq 0x8c08 <main+1108>
   0x00008a70 <+700>:   ldrb    r2, [r4, #1]
   0x00008a74 <+704>:   cmp r0, #1
   0x00008a78 <+708>:   movls   r3, #0
   0x00008a7c <+712>:   movhi   r3, #1
   0x00008a80 <+716>:   cmp r2, #100    ; 0x64
   0x00008a84 <+720>:   movne   r3, #0
   0x00008a88 <+724>:   cmp r3, #0
   0x00008a8c <+728>:   sub r2, r2, #100    ; 0x64
   0x00008a90 <+732>:   beq 0x8ac0 <main+780>
   0x00008a94 <+736>:   ldrb    r2, [r4, #2]
   0x00008a98 <+740>:   cmp r0, #2
   0x00008a9c <+744>:   movls   r3, #0
   0x00008aa0 <+748>:   movhi   r3, #1
   0x00008aa4 <+752>:   cmp r2, #0
   0x00008aa8 <+756>:   movne   r3, #0
   0x00008aac <+760>:   cmp r3, #0
   0x00008ab0 <+764>:   ldrne   r1, [pc, #704]  ; 0x8d78 <main+1476>
   0x00008ab4 <+768>:   ldrbne  r2, [r4, #3]
   0x00008ab8 <+772>:   ldrbne  r3, [r1, #3]
   0x00008abc <+776>:   rsbne   r2, r3, r2
   0x00008ac0 <+780>:   cmp r2, #0
   0x00008ac4 <+784>:   beq 0x8c08 <main+1108>
   0x00008ac8 <+788>:   ldr r0, [pc, #684]  ; 0x8d7c <main+1480>
   0x00008acc <+792>:   bl  0x29d20 <strlen>
   0x00008ad0 <+796>:   cmp r0, #6
   0x00008ad4 <+800>:   mov r1, r0
   0x00008ad8 <+804>:   bhi 0x8be4 <main+1072>
   0x00008adc <+808>:   cmp r0, #3
   0x00008ae0 <+812>:   bhi 0x8c24 <main+1136>
   0x00008ae4 <+816>:   cmp r0, #0
   0x00008ae8 <+820>:   beq 0x8b80 <main+972>
   0x00008aec <+824>:   ldrb    r3, [r4, #1]
   0x00008af0 <+828>:   cmp r3, #45 ; 0x2d
   0x00008af4 <+832>:   movne   r0, #0
   0x00008af8 <+836>:   moveq   r0, #1
   0x00008afc <+840>:   cmp r1, #1
   0x00008b00 <+844>:   movls   r2, #0
   0x00008b04 <+848>:   andhi   r2, r0, #1
   0x00008b08 <+852>:   cmp r2, #0
   0x00008b0c <+856>:   beq 0x8b44 <main+912>
   0x00008b10 <+860>:   ldrb    r3, [r4, #2]
   0x00008b14 <+864>:   cmp r3, #116    ; 0x74
   0x00008b18 <+868>:   movne   r0, #0
   0x00008b1c <+872>:   moveq   r0, #1
   0x00008b20 <+876>:   cmp r1, #2
   0x00008b24 <+880>:   movls   r2, #0
   0x00008b28 <+884>:   andhi   r2, r0, #1
   0x00008b2c <+888>:   cmp r2, #0
   0x00008b30 <+892>:   beq 0x8b44 <main+912>
   0x00008b34 <+896>:   ldrb    r3, [r4, #3]
   0x00008b38 <+900>:   cmp r3, #111    ; 0x6f
   0x00008b3c <+904>:   movne   r0, #0
   0x00008b40 <+908>:   moveq   r0, #1
   0x00008b44 <+912>:   cmp r0, #0
   0x00008b48 <+916>:   bne 0x8b80 <main+972>
   0x00008b4c <+920>:   add r5, r5, #1
   0x00008b50 <+924>:   cmp r10, r5
   0x00008b54 <+928>:   ble 0x8b90 <main+988>
   0x00008b58 <+932>:   ldr r4, [r11, r5, lsl #2]
   0x00008b5c <+936>:   ldrb    r3, [r4]
   0x00008b60 <+940>:   cmp r3, #45 ; 0x2d
   0x00008b64 <+944>:   bne 0x8820 <main+108>
   0x00008b68 <+948>:   cmp r6, #3
   0x00008b6c <+952>:   bls 0x8808 <main+84>
   0x00008b70 <+956>:   mov r0, r4
   0x00008b74 <+960>:   ldr r1, [pc, #464]  ; 0x8d4c <main+1432>
   0x00008b78 <+964>:   bl  0x29acc <strcmp>
   0x00008b7c <+968>:   b   0x8a50 <main+668>
   0x00008b80 <+972>:   add r5, r5, #1
   0x00008b84 <+976>:   cmp r10, r5
   0x00008b88 <+980>:   add r7, r4, #7
   0x00008b8c <+984>:   bgt 0x8b58 <main+932>
   0x00008b90 <+988>:   mov r0, r8
   0x00008b94 <+992>:   ldr r1, [pc, #436]  ; 0x8d50 <main+1436>
   0x00008b98 <+996>:   bl  0xa258 <vgPlain_debugLog_startup>
   0x00008b9c <+1000>:  cmp r7, #0
   0x00008ba0 <+1004>:  mov r10, r7
   0x00008ba4 <+1008>:  mov r4, #0
   0x00008ba8 <+1012>:  bne 0x8838 <main+132>
   0x00008bac <+1016>:  mov r0, #1
   0x00008bb0 <+1020>:  ldr r1, [pc, #412]  ; 0x8d54 <main+1440>
   0x00008bb4 <+1024>:  ldr r2, [pc, #452]  ; 0x8d80 <main+1484>
   0x00008bb8 <+1028>:  bl  0x9ff0 <vgPlain_debugLog>
   0x00008bbc <+1032>:  cmp r4, #0
   0x00008bc0 <+1036>:  ldr r10, [pc, #444] ; 0x8d84 <main+1488>
   0x00008bc4 <+1040>:  bne 0x8854 <main+160>
   0x00008bc8 <+1044>:  mov r0, #1
   0x00008bcc <+1048>:  ldr r1, [pc, #384]  ; 0x8d54 <main+1440>
   0x00008bd0 <+1052>:  ldr r2, [pc, #432]  ; 0x8d88 <main+1492>
   0x00008bd4 <+1056>:  ldr r3, [pc, #432]  ; 0x8d8c <main+1496>
   0x00008bd8 <+1060>:  bl  0x9ff0 <vgPlain_debugLog>
   0x00008bdc <+1064>:  ldr r8, [pc, #424]  ; 0x8d8c <main+1496>
   0x00008be0 <+1068>:  b   0x8878 <main+196>
   0x00008be4 <+1072>:  mov r0, r4
   0x00008be8 <+1076>:  ldr r1, [pc, #396]  ; 0x8d7c <main+1480>
   0x00008bec <+1080>:  mov r2, #7
   0x00008bf0 <+1084>:  bl  0x29e90 <strncmp>
   0x00008bf4 <+1088>:  rsbs    r0, r0, #1
   0x00008bf8 <+1092>:  movcc   r0, #0
   0x00008bfc <+1096>:  cmp r0, #0
   0x00008c00 <+1100>:  beq 0x8b4c <main+920>
   0x00008c04 <+1104>:  b   0x8b80 <main+972>
   0x00008c08 <+1108>:  add r8, r8, #1
   0x00008c0c <+1112>:  b   0x8ac8 <main+788>
   0x00008c10 <+1116>:  mov r0, r4
   0x00008c14 <+1120>:  ldr r1, [pc, #348]  ; 0x8d78 <main+1476>
   0x00008c18 <+1124>:  bl  0x29acc <strcmp>
   0x00008c1c <+1128>:  mov r2, r0
   0x00008c20 <+1132>:  b   0x8ac0 <main+780>
   0x00008c24 <+1136>:  mov r0, r4
   0x00008c28 <+1140>:  ldr r1, [pc, #332]  ; 0x8d7c <main+1480>
   0x00008c2c <+1144>:  bl  0x29acc <strcmp>
   0x00008c30 <+1148>:  rsbs    r0, r0, #1
   0x00008c34 <+1152>:  movcc   r0, #0
   0x00008c38 <+1156>:  cmp r0, #0
   0x00008c3c <+1160>:  beq 0x8b4c <main+920>
   0x00008c40 <+1164>:  b   0x8b80 <main+972>
   0x00008c44 <+1168>:  ldr r4, [pc, #324]  ; 0x8d90 <main+1500>
   0x00008c48 <+1172>:  ldr r1, [pc, #324]  ; 0x8d94 <main+1504>
   0x00008c4c <+1176>:  ldr r2, [pc, #268]  ; 0x8d60 <main+1452>
   0x00008c50 <+1180>:  ldr r0, [r4]
   0x00008c54 <+1184>:  bl  0x1b4c0 <fprintf>
   0x00008c58 <+1188>:  ldr r0, [r4]
   0x00008c5c <+1192>:  ldr r1, [pc, #308]  ; 0x8d98 <main+1508>
   0x00008c60 <+1196>:  bl  0x1b4c0 <fprintf>
   0x00008c64 <+1200>:  ldr r6, [pc, #304]  ; 0x8d9c <main+1512>
   0x00008c68 <+1204>:  b   0x88c8 <main+276>
   0x00008c6c <+1208>:  mov r0, #1
   0x00008c70 <+1212>:  ldr r1, [pc, #220]  ; 0x8d54 <main+1440>
   0x00008c74 <+1216>:  ldr r2, [pc, #292]  ; 0x8da0 <main+1516>
   0x00008c78 <+1220>:  ldr r3, [pc, #268]  ; 0x8d8c <main+1496>
   0x00008c7c <+1224>:  bl  0x9ff0 <vgPlain_debugLog>
   0x00008c80 <+1228>:  ldr r8, [pc, #260]  ; 0x8d8c <main+1496>
   0x00008c84 <+1232>:  b   0x8878 <main+196>
   0x00008c88 <+1236>:  ldr r0, [pc, #276]  ; 0x8da4 <main+1520>
   0x00008c8c <+1240>:  bl  0x8234 <barf>
   0x00008c90 <+1244>:  mov r0, #0
   0x00008c94 <+1248>:  ldr r1, [pc, #180]  ; 0x8d50 <main+1436>
   0x00008c98 <+1252>:  bl  0xa258 <vgPlain_debugLog_startup>
   0x00008c9c <+1256>:  mov r4, #0
   0x00008ca0 <+1260>:  b   0x8bac <main+1016>
   0x00008ca4 <+1264>:  ldr r0, [pc, #252]  ; 0x8da8 <main+1524>
   0x00008ca8 <+1268>:  bl  0x8234 <barf>
   0x00008cac <+1272>:  ldr r0, [pc, #248]  ; 0x8dac <main+1528>
   0x00008cb0 <+1276>:  bl  0x8234 <barf>
   0x00008cb4 <+1280>:  ldr r0, [pc, #244]  ; 0x8db0 <main+1532>
   0x00008cb8 <+1284>:  ldr r1, [pc, #244]  ; 0x8db4 <main+1536>
   0x00008cbc <+1288>:  movw    r2, #463    ; 0x1cf
   0x00008cc0 <+1292>:  ldr r3, [pc, #240]  ; 0x8db8 <main+1540>
   0x00008cc4 <+1296>:  bl  0xd5dc <__assert_fail>
   0x00008cc8 <+1300>:  ldr r3, [pc, #160]  ; 0x8d70 <main+1468>
   0x00008ccc <+1304>:  ldr r1, [pc, #232]  ; 0x8dbc <main+1544>
   0x00008cd0 <+1308>:  ldr r2, [r3]
   0x00008cd4 <+1312>:  mov r3, r10
   0x00008cd8 <+1316>:  str r8, [sp]
   0x00008cdc <+1320>:  bl  0x1b4e0 <sprintf>
   0x00008ce0 <+1324>:  mov r3, r4
   0x00008ce4 <+1328>:  mov r0, #1
   0x00008ce8 <+1332>:  ldr r1, [pc, #100]  ; 0x8d54 <main+1440>
   0x00008cec <+1336>:  ldr r2, [pc, #204]  ; 0x8dc0 <main+1548>
   0x00008cf0 <+1340>:  bl  0x9ff0 <vgPlain_debugLog>
   0x00008cf4 <+1344>:  mov r1, r11
   0x00008cf8 <+1348>:  mov r2, r6
   0x00008cfc <+1352>:  mov r0, r4
   0x00008d00 <+1356>:  bl  0x2ca60 <execve>
   0x00008d04 <+1360>:  ldr r3, [pc, #132]  ; 0x8d90 <main+1500>
   0x00008d08 <+1364>:  ldr r4, [r3]
   0x00008d0c <+1368>:  bl  0xd5c0 <__errno_location>
   0x00008d10 <+1372>:  ldr r0, [r0]
   0x00008d14 <+1376>:  bl  0x29b60 <strerror>
   0x00008d18 <+1380>:  mov r2, r10
   0x00008d1c <+1384>:  mov r3, r8
   0x00008d20 <+1388>:  ldr r1, [pc, #156]  ; 0x8dc4 <main+1552>
   0x00008d24 <+1392>:  str r0, [sp]
   0x00008d28 <+1396>:  mov r0, r4
   0x00008d2c <+1400>:  bl  0x1b4c0 <fprintf>
   0x00008d30 <+1404>:  mov r0, #1
   0x00008d34 <+1408>:  bl  0x12768 <exit>
   0x00008d38 <+1412>:  ldr r0, [pc, #136]  ; 0x8dc8 <main+1556>
   0x00008d3c <+1416>:  ldr r1, [pc, #112]  ; 0x8db4 <main+1536>
   0x00008d40 <+1420>:  movw    r2, #438    ; 0x1b6
   0x00008d44 <+1424>:  ldr r3, [pc, #108]  ; 0x8db8 <main+1540>
   0x00008d48 <+1428>:  bl  0xd5dc <__assert_fail>
   0x00008d4c <+1432>:          ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x000672b4
   0x00008d50 <+1436>:  andeq   r7, r6, r4, asr #5
   0x00008d54 <+1440>:  andeq   r7, r6, r0, asr #2
   0x00008d58 <+1444>:  andeq   r7, r6, r12, asr #5
   0x00008d5c <+1448>:  andeq   r7, r6, r12, lsl #5
   0x00008d60 <+1452>:  andeq   r7, r6, r0, lsr #7
   0x00008d64 <+1456>:  andeq   r7, r6, r8, lsr r4
   0x00008d68 <+1460>:  andeq   r8, r7, r0, asr #24
   0x00008d6c <+1464>:  muleq   r6, r0, r4
   0x00008d70 <+1468>:  strdeq  r4, [r8], -r0
   0x00008d74 <+1472>:  andeq   r7, r6, r0, lsr #9
   0x00008d78 <+1476>:          ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x000672b8
   0x00008d7c <+1480>:          ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x000672bc
   0x00008d80 <+1484>:  andeq   r7, r6, r4, ror #5
   0x00008d84 <+1488>:  andeq   r7, r6, r4, lsl r3
   0x00008d88 <+1492>:  andeq   r7, r6, r0, lsr #6
   0x00008d8c <+1496>:  andeq   r7, r6, r8, lsl #4
   0x00008d90 <+1500>:  andeq   r4, r8, r8, lsr #20
   0x00008d94 <+1504>:          ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x000673b0
   0x00008d98 <+1508>:  andeq   r7, r6, r8, ror #7
   0x00008d9c <+1512>:  andeq   r9, r7, r8, lsl #29
   0x00008da0 <+1516>:  andeq   r7, r6, r4, asr r3
   0x00008da4 <+1520>:  andeq   r7, r6, r8, lsl #7
   0x00008da8 <+1524>:  andeq   r7, r6, r12, asr #8
   0x00008dac <+1528>:  andeq   r7, r6, r8, ror #8
   0x00008db0 <+1532>:  andeq   r7, r6, r4, lsl #9
   0x00008db4 <+1536>:  muleq   r6, r0, r1
   0x00008db8 <+1540>:  andeq   r7, r6, r0, lsr r5
   0x00008dbc <+1544>:          ; <UNDEFINED> instruction: 0x000674bc
   0x00008dc0 <+1548>:  andeq   r7, r6, r8, asr #9
   0x00008dc4 <+1552>:  ldrdeq  r7, [r6], -r8
   0x00008dc8 <+1556>:  andeq   r7, r6, r12, lsr #8
```

Comment: There are quite a few near-duplicates showing up in "related questions" to the right; a consensus based on those suggests Valgrind probably still doesn't support ARMv5. A disassembly of the actual faulting instruction would help confirm it.

Comment: I note that neither [this ticket](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=248998) nor [this one](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=276897) seem to have gone anywhere.